# How do I get smoother radial lines in Google SketchUp?

Tags: sketchup

When I export an image in Google SketchUp, the radial lines aren't as smooth as in (by example) Vectorworks. How can I make radial lines smoother?

Comment: I assume Vectorworks exports vectorgraphics which don't have any pixelation. As far as I know Google Sketchup does not do this. To which format are you exporting?

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean the issue, that Sketchup uses straight segments to imitate curved lines. 
When creating circles and arcs, you can define how many segments you want it to consist, which also defines, how smooth it becomes. 
For details, see question ["How do I change the resolution of circles in Sketchup"](https://superuser.com/questions/161627/how-do-i-change-the-resolution-of-circles-in-sketchup)